# OData Webservice returns:Resource not found for the segment

Tags: navision

I have a strange behaviour on my testmachine..

seems like the nav service for the webserivices im testing is "broken"...

the Request returns Resource not found for the segment [WSName] ...
Seems like a WCF-Error.

It came up after i was editing a table and page, it came "another is using this table" bla bla i can not modify it.. so that was strange because this is my testmachine so the another was maybe a stucked webservice??
anyway.. after restarting all the subsequent requests came with that Resource not found for the segment ... before that it was working.

I tryied to restart all the services and reboot the pc.. nothing helped...
the webservices are correctly published....

what should I try next? Recreating the Services instances?

any advise? Much appreciated..

Comment: I have now some more information in the eventlog:Metadata for Page 21 that is published as a web service is not valid for OData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok got it. 
I added in the customer table 2 new fields "No..," and "No.."..
this caused to break the Odata Service..

So when publishing the customer page card it caused this error.

Sadly Navision did not warn when editing the page, but only when restarting the Service or at the request you get *Segment not found* because navision was not able to populate the wcf service correctly.

hope it helps someone out there..